# Can malware get installed by phone call

Tags: malware, smartphone

I'm concerned about my phone's security. I work in a very sensitive field and I received a call from a private number. What seems strange to me is the following :

- I received a call from a private number, but something was strange: The call rang less than half a second (phone was on the desk in front of me so I could see it), did not let me time to answer it, so it is definitely not for scam purposes (No time to answer, no way to call back the number).
- My phone rebooted ~10 minutes following this call (I did not linked the two events at the moment so I don't have the exact delay but it is max 15 min after, maybe just 5). I had no update required by my phone, and any way, usually my phone's updates always require manual validation and can be postponed.

I know that there are exploits, in WhatsApp for example, that allow them to install spyware using 0-day vulnerability by sending a picture that you don't even need to open, or by simply calling you on WhatsApp without the need for you to answer, and that are even able to remove the trace of the call from WhatsApp so you have no way of knowing they did it.

So my question is, is there any known instance of such hacks, and if not, is there any possibility that GSM's protocols were vulnerable to drop a payload or trigger a payload download just by calling you?

Comment: A cellular phone call? There's 0.0001% chance this could have been used used as an exploit.

Comment: Pegasus is a spyware, not a company. Pegasus itself requires an exploit to enter into the device so the exploitation of any attack vector is possible. There is no definitive measurement to know its probability of happening. Pegasus is updated to exploit new vulnerabilities.

Comment: I removed mentions of Pegasus since it was not relevant to the question at hand and would only serve as a distraction.

Comment: There are known (undisclosed) vulnerabilities in the management of calls over FaceTime in iOS. It's reasonable to assume other services and OS has similar vulnerabilities. However GSM/UMTS/LTE is more limited than data-based call services and furthermore, barring some major shifts in the past years, the GSM stack is handled by the baseband, creating one more layer of separation.  If you work in a highly sensitive field, you should be prepared to factory reset your phone(s) regularly. I'd err on the safe side and factory reset the phone or even consider tossing it if your work is very sensitive

Comment: Such vectors may exist involving sending malformed control data to the baseband or the IMT (VoLTE/VoWiFi) layer. However, the attacker will need access to the internal networks of the mobile carrier or use a fake base station. The attack will also have to be tailored to the hardware and firmware, so it would be highly sophisticated and targeted and probably not used against an average person. However, if such an attack exists, picking up the call might not be necessary to activate it, so there's little one can do either.